# Springboot Mockito : Mocked service method returning empty body

Tags: spring, junit, automated-tests, mockito, rest-assured

I have the following jersey controller.

```
  @POST
  @ApiOperation(value = "", response = Certification.class)
  public Response addCertification(@Valid CertificationRequest request) {
    return Response.ok(certificationService.addCertification(request)).build();
  }
```

I have then developed the following test using Mockito and SpringRunner.

```
@Test
    public void givenValidToken_whenAddingCertification_thenCorrect() {
        CertificationRequest certificationRequest = new CertificationRequest();
        certificationRequest.setName("name");
        Certification certification = new Certification();
        when(certificationService.addCertification(certificationRequest)).thenReturn(certification);

        given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(certificationRequest)
                .when()
                .post("/certifications")
                .then()
                .assertThat()
                .statusCode(200)
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .log()
                .all();
    }
```

Written just like that, I receive the following error when it is executed.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 26 Jun 2020 18:33:35 GMT

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected content-type "JSON" doesn't match actual content-type "".
```

On the other hand, if I add **null** in place of **certificationRequest** and send an empty body in RestAssured , it works fine.

Why does it return an empty body when sent with a request body ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one of your problems is the following:

```
when(certificationService.addCertification(certificationRequest)).thenReturn(certification);
```

You need a Matcher instead of certificationRequest. If you want to match any Request you can use `ArgumentMatchers.any()`. If you want to check for a specific Request you can use `ArgumentMatchers.eq(certificationRequest)`. Note that ArgumentMatchers.eq(...) will only work if you've provided a valid equals method (Or if you pass exactly the same argument, afair).

So for example:

```
when(certificationService.addCertification(ArgumentMatchers.eq(certificationRequest))).thenReturn(certification);
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, I would try to print the response and check what you get there.

Comment: I executed the test using your suggestions but it gives the following error ```org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:```

Comment: About the response, the body is an empty string, just like the content type.

Comment: Is the provided code your real code? This exceptions normally means you are mocking an method with two arguments, but used the ArgumentMatcher for only one of them. If your real method has more arguments you need to use ArgumentMatcher for all of them. Try ArgumentMatcher.any() for starters.

Comment: I thought of erasing some unnecessary parts. But your suggestions helped a lot. Thank you!